# Does C++ require you to initialize base class members from its derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class Base {
public:
    int a;
    Base():a(0) {}
    virtual ~Base();
}
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    int b;
    Derived():b(0) {
        Base* pBase = static_cast<Base*>(this);
        pBase->Base();
    }
    ~Derived();
}
```

Is the call to the base class constructor necessary or does c++ do this automatically? e.g.
Does C++ require you to initialize base class members from any derived class?

Comment: "*Does C++ require you to initialize base class members from any derived class?*" No, in fact it doesn't even allow you to. `Base::Base` initializes `Base`'s members, `Derived::Derived` invokes `Base::Base` then initializes `Derived`'s members.

Comment: Trying to compile this would let you see you can't call constructors like that.

Comment: @chris I'm away from a compiler and i'm working in my head at the moment. Besides it clarifies for others who are googling later =)

Comment: @WorrynAshtrod, http://ideone.com/ http://liveworkspace.org/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The base class's constructor will automatically be called before the derived class's constructor is called.

You can explicitly specify which base constructor to call (if it has multiple) using initialization lists:

```
class Base {
  public:
    int a;
    Base():a(0) {}
    Base(int a):a(a) {}
};
class Derived {
  public:
    int b;
    Derived():Base(),b(0) {}
    Derived(int a):Base(a),b(0) {}
};
```

Comment: Would you mind upvoting and accepting my answer if I've answered your question? Thanks :)

Comment: Great answer!!  I was searching for the syntax / order of member initializers of derived class and couldn't find a "good" question... luckily I came across this one.

Answer (score 1):

Base class constructors are called automatically (and before derived class contructors). So you need not, and must not, try to call base constructors manually.